# Move Gherkin's (i.e. Cucumber and Behave) Data Table to JSON

Tags: json, selenium, cucumber, bdd, python-behave

I was using Behave and Selenium to test on something that use a large amount of data. Data tables were becoming too big and making the Gherkin documentation unreadable.

I would like to move most of the data from data tables to external file such as JSON. But I couldn't find any examples on websites.

Comment: Then read the json from your steps. You will miss out on the possibility to understand what should work since you now hide the data, but maybe it is better than having scenarios that you can't read anyway. There should hopefully not be a need for an example, you have a programming language at your disposal. Use it.

Comment: Are you sure you can't simplify your scenarios/features down to the most essential Given conditions?  Or are you using large data tables for scalability testing?  In that case your Given condition could say something like "Given 100,000 users" and the programmer could then just generate 100,000 users with random names.

Comment: I was considering of using a large Data Table in the Given step, perhaps a multiple set of tables for forms. The forms usually have a lot of fields, drop down lists and radiobuttons. We have decided to use JSON so we could reuse data for many form-related tests.

The links have some Data Table-related questions and great answers.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43865871/naming-cucumbers-data-table

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43756434/move-the-headings-from-top-of-cucumbers-data-table-to-side-python

Answer (score 0):

I cannot offer an example at the moment, but I would create the JSON file as needed and give reference to the JSON file in *Given* or *Background* , then capture the value in the respective decorated method.