# Naming Cucumber's Data Table

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, bdd, python-behave

I am creating test cases on forms that could contains over 50 parameters, some of them would show up when a certain set of questions would be answered specifically.

The data tables were getting very long so I broke them into multiple data tables, each for a specific section of form.

I don't want to add every heading in the step so I want to use the data table's name instead.

Instead of:

```
Scenario:
.
.
.
When I fill in <title> <first name> <surname> ...
   |title|first name|surname|...|
   .
   .
   .
```

I want:

```
When I fill in <personal details>
And "personal details":
   |title|first name|surname|...|
   .
   .
   .
```

Is it possible to add and use the data table's name as the placeholder?

Note: I am working with Behave and Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely not possible using the <> syntax.

If you don't have many rows and your main concern is the readability of very wide tables then one option might be "transposing" the table like this:

```
When I fill in the personal details
    | Field    | Value    |
    | Title    | Prof.    |
    | Surname  | Einstein |
    | ...      |          |
```

An other option could be to define the recurring set of properties in the Background like this:

```
Background:
    Given the personal details for 'minimal personal details'
        | Surname | First name | 
        | Doe     | John       |

    And the personal details for 'insufficient personal details'
        | First name |
        | Jack       |

    And the personal details for 'all personal details'
        ...

    ...

    When I fill in personal details using 'insufficient personal details'
```

The bindings of the background register their data in the context and the 'when' binding uses the data from the context.

In either case, you'll need a binding that will tolerate missing properties and catch unknown ones.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure about what you are asking but if you are using the same details in different scenarios then it is better to use `Background` option of Cucumber. So that it will be checked before executing every scenario.

Comment: in some cases, I want to change the data, e.g. different users having their own journey through the form. For this reason, I am not using the `Background` option. 

The form is a 5 page long with a lot of data. I am looking for some cheats with Cucumber. Instead of having a very long step, 

`When I fill in <title> <first name> <surname> ........`

I want a concise, self-description step, such as 

`When I fill in "personal details"`

So I am looking for a way to assign the name, e.g. "personal details", to Behave's data table.

Answer (score 0):

Tables in Gherkin are a view on the real data (meaning a subset of columns and which rows are of interest). For readability reasons (and that somebody understands what you are doing), you should have at most 7 (plus/minus 2) columns. Maybe, the remaining data can be injected from configuration-files or config-profile database ?!? You basically use the provided Table columns as keys to be able select the configuration-row and to retrieve the remaining data from your configuration-profiles.